# Java - Serial port data extraction

Tags: java, port

I'm fairly new to Java and programming in general.
I am making an app in Java Swing that reads the data from serial port that is connected to a money counter machine. When the machine counts something, it sends count data through RS232-USB converter to the PC. I managed to make an app that finds and opens a COM port, and reads the data from the machine. This is the data that I get:

[image: Machine output]

Is it possible to extract only certain information from this output?
For example only the unit count for D10? If so how can I do it?

Idea is to write all the info separately into already defined `JTextfields`.

I tried something like this:

```
while ((line = portReader.readLine()) != null) {
                //window.ta_logs.append(line + "\n");
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);
                while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
                    String token = st.nextToken();
                    if (token.contains("D50")) {
                        data.put("D50", token.substring(2));
                    }
                    window.ta_logs.append(token);
                }
                System.out.println(line);
                System.out.println(data);

            }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does the data stream look like?

Answer (score 1):

> "*Is it possible to extract only certain information from this
> output?*"

Of course it is possible. You are already reading the data from the serial port. You can tokenize the data and store in a map.

```
// Get the data from serial port and tokenize it
Map<String, Whatever> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("D10", XXX);
data.put("D20", YYY);
...
```

Then, you can set the text in the corresponding text box

```
d10TextField.setText(data.get("D10"));
d20TextField.setText(data.get("D20"));
...
```

All you need is make this map accessible.

Comment: I tried tokenizing the input data, but to no avail. Can you please show me an example of extracting the data for "D10" for example.
I'm not sure what delimiter to use to divide the input data.

Comment: @DaniloDjurovic what do you mean? How are you processing the data right now? At the very least, you should be able to do it using bit position.

Comment: I added a code that I tried in the original post, please take a look.

Comment: How is the data stream formatted? There is no way I can troubleshoot this problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (input.available() > 0) {
                input = serialPort.getInputStream();
                int nBytes = input.available();
                int c = input.read();
                System.out.println("nBytes = " + nBytes);
                System.out.println("read " + (char) c);

                if (nBytes == 376) {
                    data.put("D10", (char) c);
                } else if (nBytes == 344) {
                    data.put("D20", (char) c);
                } else if (nBytes == 312) {
                    data.put("D50", (char) c);
                } else if (nBytes == 280) {
                    data.put("D100", (char) c);
                } else if (nBytes == 248) {
                    data.put("D200", (char) c);
                } else if (nBytes == 216) {
                    data.put("D500", (char) c);
                } else if (nBytes == 184) {
                    data.put("D1000", (char) c);
                } else if (nBytes == 152) {
                    data.put("D2000", (char) c);
                } else if (nBytes == 120) {
                    data.put("D5000", (char) c);
                }
```

I did it like this and got the wanted results.

My second question is how can I get the data if for example, D10 has more than 9pcs. In that situation, I have to take into consideration two bytes, or three if the number is 100 or more.

Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean by "9pcs"?

Comment: Also, you may want to turn this into a `switch` statement.

Comment: "_I did it like this and got the wanted results._" It seems you benefitted from my answer. The least you could've done was award me an upvote and maybe selecting my answer as the correct answer for my efforts to help you. You didn't do either. I even asked for clarification on your second question and no reply. None of this is cool at all.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the chance to reply.
What I meant by 9pcs is the following:

DENOM    UNIT
D10              0    <--- This zero will become a double-digit when the machine counts more than 9 pieces of that banknote, or a three-digit number when the machine counts more than 99 pieces.

Hope that's more clear to you.

Comment: Is there any other less complicated way to do this?
I think I overcomplicated it with how I did it, or maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Doesn't the money counting machine you're using have published specs? All the information should be there on how to process the data (how to parse it). What is the machine you are using?

Comment: Also, this line `data.put("D50", token.substring(2));` should return a `String` representation of your data. IF that works, don't process the data one character at a time. Process the entire string and that way, it will not matter whether the data is one, two, or three characters long. If the `String` value can be converted into a number, you could use one of the number classes (i.e. `Integer`, `Long`, `Double`) to convert the `String` into a number by calling the class' `parseXXX(String)` method. For example, if using `Integer`, then `data.put("D50", Integer.parseInt(token.substring(2)));`